# Data loss after upgrading instance type in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I upgraded an AWS EC2 machine 10 days ago (from t2-medium to t2-large). Again, I just upgraded today the same AWS EC2 machine (from t2-large to t2-xlarge) and after rebooting I noticed a massive loss of data (10 days of work). In fact, after changing instance type I found out it reverted to the same "state" of the machine just after doing the upgrade 10 days ago. Not less important, I have been doing snapshots periodically (twice a day), and when I try to recover from the last one, each snapshot is an exact copy of the machine after the first upgrade.

This is not the first project I have in AWS, and everytime I did a snapshot, it would always keep the very last copy of the machine. But NOT in this case. So I am really dazzled.

Can you give some hint on what could happen? Is it normal that AWS deletes data (DDBB + folder and files) when changing instance type? Do you think it might have to do with IAM policies?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EC2 user guide has information about the [EC2 Storage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Storage.html) options. To summarise:

- The EC2 instance store volume is erased when the instance is stopped or terminated.
- In contrast, EBS (Elastic Block Storage) can be mounted to a running EC2 instance (c.f. a physical hard drive). EBS volumes can be detached from one instance and attached to another instance. Moreover, you can create a snapshot of an EBS volume that is stored in S3 and you can recreate EBS volumes from that snapshot that can be attached to other EC2 instances.

The EC2 user guide provides step by step instructions:

1. [Restoring an Amazon EBS Volume from a Snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-restoring-volume.html)
2. [Attaching an Amazon EBS Volume to an Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html)

Lastly, no, this behaviour is not related to IAM policies.

Comment: The fact is that I do snapshots twice a day via CloudWatch. I created an AMI from the last snapshots before the upgrade, and the snapshot was unfortunately the same machine, 10 days before. However, the snapshot had been made just a few hours earlier. This is what I don't understand. Do you?

Comment: So by snapshot you refer to AMI snapshots (and not EBS snapshots). Please consult the "Data persistence" row in the [AMI Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ComponentsAMIs.html#storage-for-the-root-device) docs to read about the difference between `Amazon EBS-Backed AMI` and `Amazon Instance Store-Backed AMI`.

Another thing to look into is whether or not CloudWatch creates the snapshots correctly, e.g. are you still creating snapshots of the instance that you stopped using 10 ago.

Generally, I advice against hosting your own DB and rely on services like Aurora

Comment: In fact, you are right. I was doing snapshots of an old volume... My bad. Thank you for the useful insight.

Anyway, why when upgrading the instance type did I lose the data and return to the same copy of the machine 10 days before? That's something I don't understand yet.